# Run A Conditional Check On Data From One Table, Prior To Database Submission On Another Table - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have a MySQL table that works as a pivot/linking table and it initially contained two columns, both of which were foreign keys. These two columns were a `board_id` column and an `image_id` column. This table basically holds the data for when images are allocated to image boards. Obviously a board can hold multiple images, and an image can be be on multiple boards. This table is the called `boards_images` table. I'm using PHP PDO to update the database.

**The Issue**

Although a user has to be logged in to add images to the boards, because this data is publicly viewable on the submitting form via `value` attributes in form elements (i.e. a submit button and an input element) I want to be able to run a check first, to ensure the board (`board_id`) that the image is being allocated to belongs to the logged in user. A user's `user_id` is available via a logged in `$_SESSION` value. If I don't run this check a user could manually make changes to these values in the HTML and add the images to random boards of other users.

My initial approach has been that the `boards_images` linking table now contains three columns `board_id`, `image_id` and `user_id` which are foreign keys from the boards, images, and users tables respectively.

My question is how do I run the check, to ensure the `board_id` belongs to the logged in user, prior to adding an image to the board?

The boards table does have the `user_id` as a foreign key.

The code I'm currently using is below, it uses `INSERT IGNORE` to prevent duplicates (i.e. it prevents images being added to the same board more than once).

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-board-name'])) {

    $boardIdValue = $_POST['board-name'];           // board id value is shown in button's value attribute
    $imageIdValue = $_POST['image-id-for-board'];   // hidden element that shows image id of selected image

    $stmt = $connection->prepare(
        "INSERT IGNORE boards_images (board_id, image_id, user_id) 
        VALUES (:board_id, :image_id, :user_id)"
    );
    $stmt->execute([
        ':board_id' => $boardIdValue,
        ':image_id' => $imageIdValue,
        ':user_id' => $sessionId
    ]);

}
```

Will I need to a do `SELECT` of joined data first from the boards table?

When deleting an image from the board this is very simple to allocate to the logged in user, because all I need to do is add another condition to the `WHERE` clause, i.e

```
"DELETE FROM boards_images
WHERE board_id = :board_id AND image_id = :image_id AND user_id = :user_id"

// do PDO stuff
```

**Question Summary**

How do I check that when the board is being allocated an image, this board belongs to the logged in user, prior to allocating the image to that board?

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you say the `boards` table also have a `user_id` column...

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare(
    "SELECT user_id
    FROM boards
    WHERE board_id = :board_id
    LIMIT 1"
);

$stmt->execute([':board_id' => $boardIdValue]);

if($stmt->fetchColumn() == $sessionId) {
    // The board belongs to the user, add the image
}
else {
    // The board does not belong to the user, print error message etc.
}
```